# Difference of performance between two simple functions

Tags: c, performance, stack

Supposing I need to call one of these functions millions of times, what are the differences in performance between these two ?

```c
typedef struct s_tuple{
    double  x;
    double  y;
    double  z;
    double  w;
    double  m;
    double  n;
    double  o;
    double  p;
}   t_tuple;

// (1)
t_tuple tuple_mul1(const double q, t_tuple a)
{
    a.x *= q;
    a.y *= q;
    a.z *= q;
    a.w *= q;
    a.m *= q;
    a.n *= q;
    a.o *= q;
    a.p *= q;
    return a;
}

// (2)
t_tuple tuple_mul2(const double q, const t_tuple a)
{
    t_tuple b;

    b.x = a.x * q;
    b.y = a.y * q;
    b.z = a.z * q;
    b.w = a.w * q;
    b.m = a.m * q;
    b.n = a.n * q;
    b.o = a.o * q;
    b.p = a.p * q;
    return b;
}
```

**My thoughts at first:**

*resource-management:*
(2) needs to allocate memory on the stack for b, so in terms of resources 2 requires 64 more bytes than (1) per exec

*runtime:*
(1) does not allocate memory on the stack so it gains the 'stack-allocating a t_tuple' time compared to (2).

**BUT !**
I made some tests and I am completely off. Actually, 2 runs faster than 1: for 200 millions calls, (2) execs in ~1s, whereas (1) execs in ~1.55s

Edit: I compiled with cc with no options

Can someone please explain why ?

Here is my runtime-test program:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_tuple{
    double  x;
    double  y;
    double  z;
    double  w;
    double  m;
    double  n;
    double  o;
    double  p;
}   t_tuple;

// (1)
t_tuple tuple_mul1(const double q, t_tuple a)
{
    a.x *= q;
    a.y *= q;
    a.z *= q;
    a.w *= q;
    a.m *= q;
    a.n *= q;
    a.o *= q;
    a.p *= q;
    return a;
}

// (2)
t_tuple tuple_mul2(const double q, const t_tuple a)
{
    t_tuple b;

    b.x = a.x * q;
    b.y = a.y * q;
    b.z = a.z * q;
    b.w = a.w * q;
    b.m = a.m * q;
    b.n = a.n * q;
    b.o = a.o * q;
    b.p = a.p * q;
    return b;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int         i;
    long int    n;
    double      q;
    t_tuple     a;
    clock_t     start, end;

    q = 0.7;
    a.x = 1.5;
    a.y = 2;
    a.z = 35897.78;
    a.w = 4.6698;
    a.m = 5.5;
    a.n = 1065;
    a.o = 11.6887;
    a.p = 109090808.789;
    if (ac > 1)
    {
        n = atol(av[1]);
        double execution_time;
        start = clock();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            tuple_mul1(q, a);
            // tuple_mul2(q, a);
        end = clock();
        execution_time = ((double)(end - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("exec_time = %f\nn = %.f * 1e6\n", execution_time, n / 1e6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that allocating stack memory takes no time. When you call a function, it already has to allocate memory for its locals. Allocating 20 bytes and allocating 52 bytes takes the same amount of time (assuming you don't initialize the structure)

Comment: Sorry, missed the part where you did that.

Comment: An optimizing compiler could change things in ways you don't expect, for example doing nothing at all if it notices that the return value for `tuple_mul2` is never used and the function has no side effects.  Or if you assign it back to `a` both might end up as identical assembly because the end result is the same.

Comment: Look at the generated code for the two versions.

Comment: How can I access this code ?

Comment: You can have the gcc or clang output assembly code with the `-S` option, or you can look at the assembly with a debugger.

Comment: My impression is that `sizeof(t_tuple) == 64` (or `8 * sizeof(double)`) rather than 32 bytes as claimed in the question — I'm not aware of a platform where `sizeof(double) == 4`.  That affects the 'resources needed' calculation, but not too much.  But the storage for `b` in (2) may well be the same as the storage used for the return value, so there may be a copy saved.  You'd need to study the (optimized) assembly code to know what's going on and what works best and why.

Comment: It would be mildly interesting to know whether saving the result of the function call altered the timing significantly (`q = tuple_mul1(q, a);` and printing the end result after the timed loop).  You ignore the return value — which might give the compiler optimization options.  Also, making the functions `static` could alter the results (not to mention `static inline` — though the chances are that the functions would be inlined anyway if made `static`).

Comment: Thank you for these interesting suggestions, I will experiment. And you are right about sizeof(t_tuple), I edited my message replacing 32 with 64

Comment: _Side note:_ Comparison aside, passing a `struct` by _value_ is much slower than passing a _pointer_ to the struct. The compiler has to _push_ the value of `a` onto the stack. And, for `b`, it has to reserve space on the stack and copy back the results to the stack area. Change your functions to use `t_tuple *a` and `a->whatever` (instead of `a.whatever`). Likewise for `b` (you'll want to pass a `t_tuple *b` _parameter_). The overhead of passing by value and doing `return` by value will dwarf the speed of the calculations. To emphasize, add `int notused[1000000];` to the struct definition ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for these suggestions, I will try this

Comment: Also, to account for system activity, such as timeslicing, cache hit/miss, etc. you may want to change the value of `n` and run the test multiple times, taking the _minimum_ time. See my recent answer: [Why do I spend more time with binary search than with linear search?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315301/5382650) for some examples of how I recommend doing benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

What compiler did you use and with what options?

`gcc` with `-O3` produced identical assembly for both functions: https://godbolt.org/z/YhTW3zzWq

Comment: I used cc with no options. I will add it in my post
Interesting  that gcc produces the same results though

Comment: @BobDeTunis It's a bit of a maxim that comparing/benchmarking algorithms requires that we build _with_ optimization.

Comment: I did not know this thank you for that, I will use these compiler/options when I need to look at the performances